# Area of a domain with Stokes' Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

This question came up on a preliminary exam:

> Define 
>   $$g(s,t)=(x(s,t),y(s,t))=(\cos(s)+\cos(t),\sin(s)+\sin(t)),$$
>   on the region $-\pi<s<\pi$, $s<t<s+\pi$. (The function $g$ is one-to-one on this region). Suppose $\omega$ is a $1$-form defined on the image of $g$ such that $\omega(g(s,t))=-\sin(t)\,dx+\cos(t)\,dy$. Show that for any region $R$ in the image of $g$ whose boundary $\partial R$ is a closed curve, we have
>   $$\int_{\partial R}\omega = \pm\text{Area}(R).$$

My reaction to this problem is that if we knew $d\omega=1$, then we could use Stokes' theorem and be done (the $\pm$ is probably just because $\partial R$ doesn't have a defined orientation). But beyond that, I think I am making some mistake with the notation. If I simply try to substitute in the $s,t$-expressions for $x$ and $y$, to make the expression for $\omega$ depend only on $s$ and $t$, I get $\omega=dt+\cos(s-t)\,ds$.

(Related?: You can't generally integrate $\omega$ over $\partial R$, right? You need to pull back by $g$; my impression is that this is the formality behind the "substitution", but maybe I'm missing something serious.)

Comment: Another lesson learned here: it's not true that $\int_R \sigma$ is the area of $R$ when $\sigma=ds\wedge dt$ for any coordinates $s$ and $t$; you need something stronger, which seems to be specifically that $\sigma$ is a volume form whose associated measure is the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric, first of all, $\omega$ is a $1$-form on the *image* of $g$ and $R$ is a region contained in the image of $g$, so it certainly makes sense to integrate $\omega$ over $\partial R$.

Here's what I suggest:

(1) Compute $g^*\omega$ (you should get $\cos(s-t)\,ds + dt$).

(2) Compute $d(g^*\omega)$ and $g^*(dx\wedge dy)$. How do they compare?

(3) Using the fact that $g$ is one-to-one and $g^*$ is likewise, what can you now conclude?

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Some clarifications: For (1), $g^*\omega$ is a $1$-form, so I think it's not $\cos(s-t)\,ds\wedge dt$. I provided an expression in OP which I think is a computation of $g^*\omega$? In that case, I do get $d(g^*\omega)=\sin(s-t)\,dt\wedge ds$, which, based on (2), seems to be what you intended. For (3), the point is that $g$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, so we apply diffeomorphism invariance of the integral? (In which case, another factor in the $\pm$ is also whether $g$ is orientation-preserving or -reversing)

Comment: Agh, I typed too quickly. Corrected. Thanks. And, yes, you can conclude, in fact, that $d\omega = dx\wedge dy$. I don't think you need the $\pm$. (Recall that $d(g^*\omega) = g^*(d\omega)$.)